# TimeoutError {message: "Request timed out after 30000ms", stack: "TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka-node with cofluent kafka which runs inside a docker. Do you know what this error means ?Is this something to do with the kafka node library ?

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when the client is not able to connect to the broker ( but the zookeeper is accessible ) , so the producer or consumer application times out about 30 seconds.

Check the docker configuration and the exposed ports in docker image.